# Swift value type semantics and impact of bindings

Tags: swift, swiftui

I was recently looking at Apple's sample code for a `ReferenceFileDocument` based SwiftUI document app: [Building a Document-Based App with SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/building_a_document-based_app_with_swiftui)

The two main data types, `Checklist` and `ChecklistItem`, are defined as `structs`. There is also a helper struct `BindingCollection` that converts a binding to a collection of elements into a collection of bindings to the individual elements. The app relies on bindings to these structs.

However, in some ways, isn't a binding to a struct circumnavigating value-type semantics? Any piece of code that is passed the Binding can alter the value, rather than a copy of the value? How does SwiftUI know that the struct has been updated without a publisher?

Last question: if I'd been writing this app myself, I would have made `Checklist` a class, conforming to `ObservableObject` publishing its `items` property. This would have avoided the helper function, and use of bindings. What are the benefits of the struct / binding approach in the example code?

Comment: I don't think that I agree that using a Binding is "circumnavigating value-type semantics". In fact, I think by using a Binding it is clear that you are probably *not* mutating a reference-type object but instead performing an operation that will result in a new value type or value type collection.

Comment: `isn't a binding to a struct circumnavigating value-type semantics?` - no, a binding exposes a `Publisher` which sends events when the data changes. SwiftUI views subscribe to that publisher, and update the UI in respect to the new values that were published.